# Send files with java socket

Tags: java, sockets

i am sending files from two java applications here the source code of the server and the client

```
public class FileClient {

    private Socket s;

    public FileClient(String host, int port, String file) {
        try {
            s = new Socket(host, port);
            sendFile(file);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void sendFile(String file) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        while ((fis.read(buffer) > 0)) {
            dos.write(buffer);
        }

        fis.close();
        dos.close();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileClient fc = new FileClient("192.168.0.167", 1988, "C:/Users/mhattabi/Desktop/fileData.txt");
    }

}
```

and here the source code of the server

```
public class FileServer extends Thread {

    private ServerSocket ss;

    public FileServer(int port) {
        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket clientSock = ss.accept();
                saveFile(clientSock);

            //  ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void saveFile(Socket clientSock) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(clientSock.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileData.txt");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        int filesize = 15123; // Send file size in separate msg
        int read = 0;
        int totalRead = 0;
        int remaining = filesize;
        while((read = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            totalRead += read;
            System.out.println("read " + totalRead + " bytes.");
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        fos.close();
        dis.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileServer fs = new FileServer(1988);
        fs.start();
    }

}
```

the problem that in the server i received the file but there is extra character in it look like this.Any help will be appreciated thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usual problem.

```
while ((fis.read(buffer) > 0)) {
    dos.write(buffer);
}
```

You're ignoring the count returned by the read, and assuming that it filled the buffer. It should be:

```
while ((count = fis.read(buffer) > 0)) {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Curiously enough you have this right in the server. NB You don't need a `DataOutputStream` here.

Answer (score -1):

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
```

I think the" extra character" come from this place;every time you write 4096 byte
,at last time it happened less than 4096 byte.and then you get extra character

Comment: It does not 'come from this place'. You're on the right track, but you've mis-identified the error site, and you haven't provided an actual solution.